# JQuery "tap" event fires twice

Tags: jquery, events, tap

I have a real issue with JQuery mobile "tap" event. It fires twice and i don´t seem to be able to stop it.

The issue is that i have one page index.html that when you tap on a button you move on to page2.html. The problem is that when you do a quicktap you will move to page2.html and then it will tap again on that page and that causes serious problems. Is there anyway i can fix this? I have tried return false; but it doesn´t work. Here is the code i use:

```
$("#read").on('tap',function()
{
    $.mobile.changePage('pages/reader/reader.html');
    return false;
});
```

UPDATE:
After doing ALOT of testing it doesn´t seem to be the event that is fired twice. It just seems that an extra tap is SOMETIMES followed to the other page so what other buttons is on the next page is tapped. This is a SERIOUS issue and i can´t release it like this.

Anyone have ideas why JQuery mobile behave in this sucky way?

Comment: perhaps this could be reported in jQuery Mobile issue tracker? it sounds like a bug...

Comment: I have seen other have the same problem....but no solution. I really don´t know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I donot have much experience with jquerymobile but this could be very well cause of eventPropagation, stopping the event to propagate to its parent might help.

try this:

```
$("#read").on('tap',function(e)
{
    $.mobile.changePage('pages/reader/reader.html');
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#read").on('tap',function()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.hasClass("tapped")) {
        $this.addClass("tapped");
        $.mobile.changePage('pages/reader/reader.html');
    }
});
```

And if you need to re-enable that button, just removeClass("tapped"), as you probably know.